# how to iterate from a list in react?

Tags: reactjs

i am filtering certain cities into "citiesList" and then mapping them into dropdown component but the filter is done but map part is not excetued.

```
citySearched= (cities,city)=>{
      let citiesList= [...cities];
      citiesList= citiesList.filter(c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(city.toLowerCase()))
      .map(c => (<DropDown key= {c.id} citySearch= {c.name}/>));
      console.log(citiesList,city);
    }
```

Comment: I suspect that all you need to do is to return `citiesList` in your `citySearched`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use curly braces with arrow function return is not implicit, so you need to return explicitly as

```
citySearched= (cities,city)=>{
  let citiesList= [...cities];
  citiesList= citiesList.filter(c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(city.toLowerCase()))
  .map(c => (<DropDown key= {c.id} citySearch= {c.name}/>));
  return citiesList;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You should return what you have rendered inside the function:

```
citySearched= (cities,city)=>{
      let citiesList= [...cities];
      citiesList= citiesList.filter(c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(city.toLowerCase()))
      .map(c => (<DropDown key= {c.id} citySearch= {c.name}/>));
      console.log(citiesList,city);
      return citiesList
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the filtered mapped data which will be rendered on page.

```
let citySearched = (cities, city) => {
    let citiesList = [...cities];
    return citiesList.filter(c => c.login.includes(city.toLowerCase()))
        .map(c => (<DropDown key= {c.id} citySearch= {c.name}/>));
}
```